# match all key/val pairs

Tags: clojure, hugsql

Original query:

```
-- :name select*-list
-- :command :query
-- :result :raw
-- :doc Select all lists.
-- parameters()
SELECT * FROM list;
```

I want to pass in arbitrary key/val pairs and get matching results. For example:

`(select*-list db-spec {:name "Fruit" :type "Foo"})`

should result in:

```
SELECT * FROM list 
WHERE name = 'Fruit'
AND type = 'Foo';
```

I can think of a few ugly ways to accomplish this but it's likely I'm overlooking some nice way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

JDBC has some great shortcuts out from the box. One of them is [find-by-keys](https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/find-by-keys). It does exactly what you want: takes a map of key/value pairs and composes a set of `WHERE` clauses connected with `AND`:

```
(jdbc/find-by-keys db-spec :users {:name "John" :age 42 :city "Chita"})
```

will turn out to

```
select from users
where
  name = 'John'
  and age = 42
  and city = 'Chita';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `java-jdbc.sql`

```
(require '[java-jdbc.sql :as sql])

(jdbc/query db-spec
  (sql/select * :fruit (sql/where {:appearance "ripe"})))
;; -> ({:grade 8.4, :unit "carton", :cost 12, :appearance "ripe", :name "Plum"})
```

Please see:

- [The Clojure Cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-03_manipulating-an-SQL-database.asciidoc) (I recommend buying a printed copy).
- The JDBC pages at [clojure-doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/home.html)